# Get todays rows from oracle database

Tags: php, oracle

I have been working much with local phpmyadmin and now I am suppose to check my code functionalities with a lot of data from the oracle database which I have never experienced before. So I want to know how I can get only the rows of today's. or compare it in any other way if you can think of one or two. here is the what i have tried so far according to what I've read on SO questions but doesn't seem to help much.

```
      $sql1 = "SELECT a.*, ROWNUM rnum FROM  (
          SELECT alert_time AS qen, count(*) AS Total FROM alert 
          GROUP BY alert_time 
      ) a WHERE TRUNC(sysdate) = TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP(alert_time)))";
```

The `alert_time` column returns something like "Wed Aug 24 12:11:05 2016"

The only thing I want to do here is to fetch all the rows from the table `alerts` that has been added only today so that the query will execute faster let alone giving me what I want.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because you explicitly mention Oracle.

Comment: what is the datatype of your alert_time column ?

Comment: i don't currently have the access to know that but its likely to be `Date`. i can tell from its row `22-AUG-16 04.17.29.000000 AM` right? or let me know how if there is anyway to print out the datatype?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM alert 
WHERE alert_time >= TRUNC(sysdate);
```

If there are future alerts:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM alert 
WHERE alert_time >= TRUNC(sysdate) AND alert_time < TRUNC(sysdate + 1);
```

You only need `TO_TIMESTAMP()` if `alert_time` is being stored as a character.  You only need `rownum` if you want to add an enumeration column to the output.

Comment: i just tried `SELECT *
              FROM alert  
              WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(alert_time) >= TRUNC(sysdate) AND TO_TIMESTAMP(alert_time) < TRUNC(sysdate + 1)` and it shows an error like **a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected in**

Comment: @King . . . As I mention in the answer, it is unclear to me why you would be using `TO_TIMESTAMP()` for this purpose.  If `alert_time` is (for some unreasonable reason) stored as a string, then `TO_TIMESTAMP()` should have a format string as the second argument.